# creating 2 timer

Tags: java, timertask

I have MyTimer which needs to parameters:

```
public MyTimer(long mac, String ipAddress){
    this.macAddress = mac;
    this.ip = ipAddress;

    timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.info("mac " + String.valueOf(macAddress) + " ip " + ip);

        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 30*1000,30*1000);
    log.info("timer created, mac:" String.valueOf(macAddress) + " ip " + ip);
}
```

From another class:

```
MyTimer timer1 = new MyTimer(mac1, ip1);
MyTimer timer2 = new MyTimer(mac2, ip2);
```

When created everything works fine:

```
Oct 23, 2012 1:36:43 PM spb.MyTimer <init>
INFO: timer created, mac: 26954208388119 ip 77.209.184.53
Oct 23, 2012 1:36:43 PM spb.MyTimer <init>
INFO: timer created, mac 26954208388118 ip 178.139.7.27
```

But, when the timer reaches the delay:

```
Oct 23, 2012 1:39:13 PM spb.MyTimer$1 run
INFO: mac 26954208388119 ip 178.139.7.27
Oct 23, 2012 1:39:13 PM spb.MyTimer$1 run
INFO: mac 26954208388118 ip 178.139.7.27
```

How should this issue solved?

Comment: Your `MyTimer` should extend `TimerTask` so that it can store state, by state I mean IP address and Mac address and run `MyTimer` rather than Seperate `TimerTask`

Comment: I think I know what your problem could be. Please post the code which sets the variables ip1 and ip2 in your other class.

Comment: It a SSLSocket named client: client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()

Comment: I did not get such output. I got exactly what should be. your code is working in my system. :/

Comment: Quoi, could you post the full code in order I check it for mistakes?